# Checking Palidrome in C++, some outputs are working some aren't

Tags: c++, c++17

```
int reverse(int);

int main(){
    cout<<"Enter a number : ";
    int n{};
    cin>>n;
    int n_alias{n};
    int m=reverse(n);
    
    if (n_alias==m){
        cout<<"The number "<<n<<" in reverse is "<<m<<endl;
        cout<<"So "<<n<<" a palindrome\n\n";
    }
    
    else{
        cout<<"The number "<<n<<" in reverse is "<<m<<endl;
        cout<<"So "<<n<<" not a palindrome\n\n";
    }
}

int reverse(int q){
    vector<int> vec{};
    int t{};
    
    while (q>0){
        t=q%10;
        vec.push_back(t);
        q-=t;
        q/=10;
    }
    size_t u{vec.size()};
    int b{};
    for (size_t i{};i<u;i++){
        
        b+=(vec[i])*pow(10,u-i-1);
    }
    return b;
}
```

Now 1234321 is working fine, but it is giving wrong result for 121, 12321 and 123454321. I don't know why thats happening when it is using the same algorithm for both test cases.

[image]

Comment: Since you know input that is failing, you could take one of them and use a *debugger* to step through your code statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values. That's the usual way to solve these kind of problems.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I used debugger but it's not showing the variables in 'locals'. I've asked my instructor about that. i will use it again once he answers me

Comment: Argh. Why do you throw floating-point into the mix?

Comment: What' specifically is wrong about the output? [This](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4595af25751ce742) looks like the expected output.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. When I copy and paste this example code, plus the omitted include and using statements, it correctly states that 121, 12321, and 123454321 are palindromes. It also correctly states that 122 and 12322 aren't palindromes.

Comment: @Deduplicator when did i used floating point numbers?

Comment: @churill when i enter 121, it says the number in reverse is 120 when it should be 121

Comment: @NathanPierson is 12321 working fine on your system? i've edited it and added the screenshot where it outputs wrong result with that test case.

Comment: You used floating-point by calling [`pow()`](//en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow).

Comment: @sudhanshu Interesting. I can reproduce this behaviour neither with g++ nor with msvc. How do you compile? And please check that you posted the correct code that causes the error. Anyway, I think the answers you have are good enough to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

Floating-point arithmetic is not real number arithmetic. Both mantissa and exponent (generally base 2, though base 10 is not unheard of) have a restricted range.

Proving that including floating-point in your integer calculations is accurate is a decidedly non-trivial task, even if you can depend on the floating-point package used in your implementation being completely accurate, and don't allow any shortcuts. Just avoid it.

Anyway, reversing a number can be done simpler:

```
auto reverse(unsigned long long  n) {
    constexpr auto base = 10u;
    unsigned long long r = 0;
    for (; n > 0; n /= base)
        r = r * base + n % base;
    return r;
}
```

Comment: Literally a case of `double`, `double` toil and trouble.

Comment: are you suggesting me to stop using 'size_t'?

Comment: @sudhanshu Using `size_t` is a bit random there, but at least it is unsigned, and probably not smaller than `int`. But it could be.

Answer (score 1):

One more option:

```
auto rev = [](int n)
{
    auto s = std::to_string(n);
    return std::stoi(std::string(s.rbegin(), s.rend()));
}

cout << rev(1234) << endl;
```

Output:

```
4321
```